# Going from Vagrant in development to chef-solo in production, and getting a "FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for #<Chef::Role" error

Tags: chef, ubuntu-10.10, chef-solo

So I have a set of cookbooks/roles that are configured to work with vagrant.  I am now in the process of deploying an application, and I want to run these identical cookbooks using chef-solo on my server.  So I simply installed chef-solo(the same version that I am using with vagrant), and attempted to call the following command:

```
sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j roles/clusterflunk_dev.json
```

Unfortunately, the following error was generated:

```
[Fri, 27 Jul 2012 08:20:28 +0100] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.8 ***
[Fri, 27 Jul 2012 08:20:29 +0100] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[Fri, 27 Jul 2012 08:20:29 +0100] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for #  <Chef::Role:0x7f6848a05638>
```

I'm not sure how the same version of chef would yield different results, I'm obviously making a mistake somewhere.  I'm using Ubuntu Server 10.10.

Comment: Can you post your Vagrantfile and some lines of context from  `/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out` which show where the error happens (line nos), and explain how you are passing the roles to the server instance of chef-solo?

Comment: you can give the `chef-solo -l debug` options to get some verbose logging (pastebin.com that, or open a ticket on opscode.com with that output)

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to determine what is causing the issue, by looking at the errors, I would suggest to upgrade chef to the current release version (upgrade 10.8 to 10.24.4, or better make the jump to 11.x) using the omni-installer.

http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

Other users have reported similar errors, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181226/chef-solo-run-list-error-with-json) for an example, and there are a number of closed JSON related fixed tickets since Chef 0.10.8